# How do you build accessible applications for X11?

Tags: x11, xlib

I'm building an application using xlib/x11. What can I do to make sure the application is accessible and usable by people using screen readers and other assistive technology? Is there documentation/standards about this stuff somewhere?

Comment: Seems border-line off-topic since asking for resources. Or else, is too broad. I tried to provide an answer.

Comment: my research didn't reveal anything. my guess is there is nothing like that embedded in xlib/x11. however there might be other tools that will do it for you: http://linux-speakup.org/

Answer (score -1):

> I'm building an application using xlib/x11.

**Don't do that** (coding just above X11 an accessible application). Raw Xlib is too low-level. (You'll need to work many years if you only use Xlib, and by that time X11 could become obsolete, e.g. replaced with [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server_protocol))).

You really want to **use some [toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit)** like [Qt](http://qt.io) or [GTK](http://gtk.org/), [etc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits); not just Xlib.... Life is too short to avoid toolkits (which are built above Xlib and other things). See also [EWMH](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html)

And both Qt and Gnome (above GTK)  have accessibility guidelines and features. Read about [Qt accessibility](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/accessible.html) and about [Gnome/GTK accessibility](https://developer.gnome.org/accessibility-devel-guide/stable/gad-how-it-works.html.en). So choose some toolkit providing accessibility features and use them.

Or consider developing a web application, perhaps by using some HTTP server library like [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/). [Web accessibility](https://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/accessibility.php) is also well documented.

If you really want to only use Xlib (without any toolkit), you need to implement accessibility yourself (probably with some other software). That (and developing your own widgets...) will take you a lot of time (years of work), if you don't take advantage of *existing* software and guidelines related to accessibility.